# How to Update SimpleDialog in flutter without stateful builder inside as if used, the value outside is not updated

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, runtime-error, setstate

My query is simple. I have `Icons.add` and `Icons.remove` based on condition whether an array has a value or not. and that array is converted to string with`.join()` in `flutter`.

If I use `Stateful Builder from flutter` the value inside the `simpleDialog` is updated and so the icons change as I need, but then I don't get the data in the screen from where I am calling the `dailog widget`.

Right now I am able to access the data I desire, just the icons are not updating.

```dart
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
  // set up the SimpleDialog
  SimpleDialog dialog = SimpleDialog(
    title: const Text('Choose Your Health Issue'),
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: hi.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () => setState(() {
                      var x = hi[index].title;
                      if(hIssue.contains(x)){
                          hIssue.removeAt(hIssue.indexOf(x));                        
                          print("removing -> $x");
                      } else {
                          hIssue.add(x);
                          print("adding -> $x");
                      }
                    }),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            hi[index].title.toString(), 
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                          ),
                          (hIssue.contains(hi[index].title)) ? Icon(Icons.remove) : Icon(Icons.add)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return dialog;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want the result from the choice given to the user on the Dialog. The [showDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) function returns a future. This future will return you the value of the decision.

```
void showDialogAlert(context){
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return dialog;
    }
  ).then((valueFromDialog){
    print('do something with the value $valueFromDialog');
  });
}
```